# How to add the hover class using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've tried to implement for all the `<div>` effect when the page loads.

```
 jQuery('.postCenter').addClass("hiddenClass").viewportChecker({
        classToAdd: 'visibleClass animated bounce',
        offset: 200
       });
```

Now this is working only when the page is loading. I need the same effect when I hover the mouse through that `<div>`

I tried this but didn't work.

```
$('.nom-img').hover(function(){

    $('.tag-nom').removeClass('animated');
    $('.tag-nom').removeClass('bounce');

    $('.tag-nom').addClass('animated');
    $('.tag-nom').addClass('bounce');
});
```

My Markup is this:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 postLeft">
   <h2>Topeka, Kansas</h2>
   <div class="nom-img">
     <a href="topeka.html"><img src="img/xxxxxx"></a>
   </div>
   <div class="tag-nom postCenter"> <a href="#"><img src="XXX"></a>
      <h4><a href="#">vsdvsdvsdvsdv</a></h4>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want `tag-nom` to be animated when I hover the div `nom-img`

I have 6 of such columns. So only the corresponding `tag-nom`should be animated on hover. How can I do this?

Comment: what you have to use is the $(this) selector instead of the class selector inside the hover function for the add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify the hover function to accept two methods,i.e. mouseenter and mouseleave respectively. you will also need to target `.tag-nom` that is next sibling element of hovered element:

```
$('.nom-img').hover(function(){
  $('.tag-nom').not($(this).next()).removeClass('animated bounce')
  $(this).next().addClass('animated bounce');
},function(){
  $(this).next().removeClass('animated bounce');
});
```

Comment: @user1012181: please mark the answer if it helped you, it will help others to know whcih is the most useful answer

Comment: @Milind Anantwar, On the first hover, this action is not working. When I hover again, it works. And when I scroll down and goes up, the effect shows again even without the hovering. What might be the problem?

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.nom-img').hover(function(){

    $('.tag-nom').addClass('animated').addClass('bounce');
}, function(){

    $('.tag-nom').removeClass('animated').removeClass('bounce');
});
```